# Unable to install Windows product key - error 0x80041015

Tags: windows, product-key, licensing, wmi

I decided to install a proper product key for my Windows 8.1.

I tried the PC Settings applet, but it refused to accept my key.

I tried using `slmgr /ipk ....`, but got error WBEM_E_TRANSPORT_FAILURE 0x80041015.

I debugged the `slmgr.vbs` script and tried to use the underlying WMI:
`wmic:root\cli>PATH SoftwareLicensingService where Version="6.3.9600.16497" call InstallProductKey ProductKey="..."
Execute (\\PC\root\cimv2:SoftwareLicensingService.Version="6.3.9600.16497")->InstallProductKey() (Y/N/?)? y
ERROR:
Description = Transport failure`

How to fix this problem and install the product key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this Windows licensing problem by installing a Microsoft **Office** hotfix - http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2968890/en-us